# Flutter web ignore resize

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I would like to make my web app does not resize/responsive when the screen become smaller. For example when i decrease my browser size, instead of its adapting to the width and height, i want the web app to ignore it and user can just scroll up, down, left and right to view the web.

[image: Example of website where i can decrease the browser size and the ui will ignore it]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use a [`LayoutBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) and eventually add a [`SingleChildScrollView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) when the size becomes lower than your app expects.

This `MinSize` widget accomplishes it.

```dart
/// Starts scrolling [child] vertically and horizontally when the widget sizes
/// reaches below [minWidth] or [minHeight]
class MinSize extends StatefulWidget {
  const MinSize({
    Key? key,
    this.minWidth,
    this.minHeight,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;

  final double? minWidth;

  final double? minHeight;

  @override
  State<MinSize> createState() => _MinSizeState();
}

class _MinSizeState extends State<MinSize> {
  late final _verticalController = ScrollController();
  late final _horizontalController = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        final shouldScrollVertical = widget.minHeight != null &&
            constraints.maxHeight <= widget.minHeight!;
        final contentHeight =
            shouldScrollVertical ? widget.minHeight : constraints.maxHeight;
        final verticalPhysics = shouldScrollVertical
            ? const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()
            : const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics();

        final shouldScrollHorizontal =
            widget.minWidth != null && constraints.maxWidth <= widget.minWidth!;
        final contentWidth =
            shouldScrollHorizontal ? widget.minWidth : constraints.maxWidth;
        final horizontalPhysics = shouldScrollHorizontal
            ? const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()
            : const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics();

        return Scrollbar(
          controller: _verticalController,
          thumbVisibility: shouldScrollVertical,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            controller: _verticalController,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            physics: verticalPhysics,
            child: Scrollbar(
              interactive: true,
              controller: _horizontalController,
              thumbVisibility: shouldScrollHorizontal,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                controller: _horizontalController,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                physics: horizontalPhysics,
                child: UnconstrainedBox(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: contentHeight,
                    width: contentWidth,
                    child: widget.child,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Alternatively, try the [`InteractiveViewer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer-class.html) to freely move the content in the app window.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `SizedBox` with a fixed height/width property

Comment: Could you expand a bit more into your answer? Explaining "why" SizedBox works in this case. (providing links to the docs helps as well with a small text snippet)